# Create table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, create-table

I want to create a table in Oracle, with sql developer and I received an error! This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE "DASHBOARD"."DASH_OMC_CASES" 
   (    "OBJID" NUMBER, 
    "CASE_ID" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "CREATION_TIME" DATE, 
    "MELDUNGS_TYP" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "ELEMENT" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "INITIATOR" VARCHAR2(75 BYTE), 
    "ERSTELLER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "BEGINN" DATE, 
    "ENDE" DATE, 
    "STATUS_NGM" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "STATUS_SBM" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STATUS_TE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "URSACHE_KURZ" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE), 
    "ALARM_BEGINN" DATE, 
    "ALARM_ENDE" DATE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "ALR_STAG_DATEN" ;
```

and this is the error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DASHBOARD' ist nicht vorhanden
01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    User does not exist in the system.
*Action:   Verify the user name is correct.
```

Comment: You are trying to create a table in the schema of the user `DASHBOARD` but apparently that user does not exist. Most probably you don't want to prefix the table name with the owner at all.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your statement says you want to make a table names `DASH_OMC_CASES` in the schema `DASHBOARD`. You have either no privileges to see the contents of that schema, or it simply doesn't exists.

Try to remove the `DASHBOARD.` part of your statement if you don't want to create it in that specific schema:

```
CREATE TABLE DASH_OMC_CASES
...
```

Else make sure your account has enough privileges.

Comment: I removed the DASHBOARD and now I received another error           SQL Error: ORA-00959: Tablespace 'ALR_STAG_DATEN' nicht vorhanden
00959. 00000 -  "tablespace '%s' does not exist"

Comment: @eu127: What do you think `TABLESPACE "ALR_STAG_DATEN"` does? Remove it.

Comment: This is the time when you need to use your knowledge to solve an issue yourself @eu127. If the error message you're getting is that something doesn't exist it's normally worth checking to see if it _does_ exist before asking a question. The internet doesn't have access to your database and can't tell you.